# For which values of real parameter "m" the system...

Tags: linear-algebra

For which values of real parameter "m" the system of linear equations
[image]

has an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: Do you know Gauss-Jordan method?

Comment: Frankly, I worked rarely with this method, but I will try to understand the topic.

Comment: After you finish your trial let us help you if you face any problem

Comment: Glad to help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Put in a matrix, row-reduce and see what the last equation is in terms of $m$. To have an infinite number of solutions, the last equation needs to be $0 = 0$.

Comment: But can I use determinants instead of row-reducing, because I am used to solving linear equations using determinants? I know, for example that if we want to have one solution the determinant shouldn't be zero, but in the case of this exercise with infinite solution I have no idea!

Comment: @JohnG. I think the determinant here cannot be used - when determinant is 0, you have either no solutions or infinite solutions, but you cannot characterize which one.

Comment: Thank you gt6989b for you help! I'll try what you proposed